# Vue modal always re render

Tags: javascript, laravel, performance, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

Im trying to make modal that append mapItems by clicking some button and open the modal,
but everytime modal is show/hide, modal dialog always re-render.

```
<div v-for="(item, key) in mapItems">
    <b-modal :id="`map${key}`">
        <iframe width="600" height="450" style="border:0" loading="lazy" allowfullscreen :src="mapSrc(item.mapUrl)"> </iframe>
    </b-modal>
</div>
```

is it possible to make modal dialog keep on dom, i want to make minimum request on server

Thank you in Advance

Comment: What if you put the modal in the component and use props to pass the parameters like mapUrl? Also, put the modal out of the `v-for` means do not generate modal for every mapItem you have and create one modal and pass different parameters.

Comment: @ImanShafiei I want to make it dynamic, I have a list, when the list is clicked it will open the modal that has map inside, so the map is render when needed, i used "v-for" for that.

Comment: Always use `key` with v-for. This may not solve the problem but it's a part of it.